# How to get height of element compose before drawing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How to get height of element Compose before drawing ?

I tried get height after measure(), but measuredHeight returns 0

For example from this element

```
val composeView = ComposeView(context).apply {
     setContent {
         Box(modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp))
     }
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "before drawing"? Compose will have to do a layout step before it can tell you how big anything is, that's just common sense.